# Where can I practice phowa online?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, vajrayana

As a lay person, I’d like to find resources online to practice phowa because of a lack of masters I can meet in person where I live. Are there any good resources on the internet to achieve phowa? And has anyone here done the phowa practice?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean phowa as transferring your consciousness to another body? one of the 6 yogas of naropa?
This is not something written about, afaik only the karma kaguya practice this, 1 tibetan sect that is deeply rooted in oral transmission from master to student and such a practice would only be taught to monastics and people who are adept as it is an impediment to liberation, its a tangent. Something you would essentially have to dedicate your entire life towards.

If you mean phowa as in the prayers for the dead ceremony to help a dead persons consciousness travel well, well there are probably many books about the practice, it is essentially a colloquial Tibetan funerary rite based upon the Tibetan book of the dead.

I know kelsang gyatso living meaningfully, dying joyfully book explains the latter practice (I have read it, its useless for me)